# Proving an equation is not a formula for primes

Tags: linear-algebra

I was helping a GCSE student with a question from a past paper that asked something along the lines of:

> Prove that $x^2+x+11$ does not always output a prime number.

The correct 'proof' was to simply substitute 10 into the equation to obtain 121, obviously not a prime number. However, this felt like a really clumsy way to do the proof, and to me it felt like it took the easy option.

Is there a more mathematical way to prove this?

Comment: Why is it clumsy to find a counter-example? That's a very important thing to understand in mathematics - that something isn't true for all $x$ if you find an $x$ for which it is true.

Comment: A single counter-example disproves a conjecture. This is a core concept in mathematics; perhaps one of the most "mathematical" concepts of all.

Comment: Plugging in 11 seems like a more obvious counterexample, not requiring any calculation at all.

Comment: [A proof for **every** non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Prime_formulas_and_polynomial_functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more mathematical way would be to plug in 11. If you do this you get something that clearly cannot be a prime number, since
$$
11\mid 11^2 + 11 + 11,
$$
and you don't have to calculate anything.

You can also generalise this theorem: there is no non-constant polynomial $P$ such that $P(x)$ is prime for all $x\in\mathbb N$. Suppose we have such a polynomial $P$ of degree $n\geq 2$. Then we have $P(1)=p$ for some prime $p$. Now look at $P$ in $\mathbb F_p[X]$. Note that in $\mathbb F_p[X]$ we have $(1+ap)^m = 1$ for all $a\in\mathbb N$ because of Newtons Binomium (every term is divisable by $p$ except for the first one). This gives us $P(1) = P(1+ap)$ in $\mathbb F_p[X]$. We know that in $\mathbb Z[X]$ the value $P(1+ap)$ is prime for all $a\in\mathbb N$ and since it it divisable by $p$ this gives us $P(1p+a)=p$. But then we have at least $n+1$ values where $P$ is equal to $p$ so $P$ has to be a constant function. This contradicts with the fact that $\deg(P)=n\geq 2$.

Comment: This is as 'mathematical' as plugging in $10$ and finding it is divisible by $11$, just a bit simpler to see.

Comment: I like it because you don't have to try several numbers before you reach something that is not prime, but I can understand it seems a bit like a trick.

Comment: No non-constant polynomial, of course...

Comment: @user314 The general principle that does make it more mathematical in some sense is that if you have a polynomial allegedly generating primes, setting the variable to the constant (or, occasionally, a multiple of the constant) will not generate a prime number because it will be divisible by the constant.